# How to disable the "corner to corner" feature in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Every time I want to place an image near another in inkscape, is trying to position it close to one of its corner. I could avoid this using the Shift key, but how can I disable that feature so I don't need to press the shift key which is annoying.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That feature is called *snapping.*

- *View → Show/Hide → Snap Controls Bar* gives you a control bar whose first button allows you to deactivate snapping. The bar also allows you to activate and deactivate specific types of snapping. The one that annoys you sounds like *Snap to bounding box corners.*
- You can also toggle snapping with the <kbd>%</kbd> key.
- In older versions of Inkscape, you can also disable snapping with *View → Snap.*

Comment: unchecking it doesn't seem to actually work for me (version 0.92) but hitting % does. Not sure whether I'm crazy or it's a bug.

Comment: Holy mother of Pearl, thank you. That snap to corner has been infuriating me the last year of using inkscape and I'm just learing about the % thing

Comment: shift % or unchecking view>show/hide doesn't work for me either
I guess its a bug